# JavaFX animated line charts

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, linechart

```
package harika;

import javafx.animation.AnimationTimer;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.chart.LineChart;
import javafx.scene.chart.NumberAxis;
import javafx.scene.chart.XYChart;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentLinkedQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadFactory;


public class ChartWork extends Application {

private static final int MAX_DATA_POINTS = 50;
private int xSeriesData = 0;
private XYChart.Series<Number, Number> series1 = new XYChart.Series<>();
private XYChart.Series<Number, Number> series2 = new XYChart.Series<>();
private XYChart.Series<Number, Number> series3 = new XYChart.Series<>();
private ExecutorService executor;
private ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Number> dataQ1 = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<>();
private ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Number> dataQ2 = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<>();
private ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Number> dataQ3 = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<>();

private NumberAxis xAxis;

private void init(Stage primaryStage) {

    xAxis = new NumberAxis(0, MAX_DATA_POINTS, MAX_DATA_POINTS / 10);
    xAxis.setForceZeroInRange(false);
    xAxis.setAutoRanging(false);
    xAxis.setTickLabelsVisible(false);
    xAxis.setTickMarkVisible(false);
    xAxis.setMinorTickVisible(false);

    NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis();

    // Create a LineChart
    final LineChart<Number, Number> lineChart = new LineChart<Number, Number>(xAxis, yAxis) {
        // Override to remove symbols on each data point
        @Override
        protected void dataItemAdded(Series<Number, Number> series, int itemIndex, Data<Number, Number> item) {
        }
    };

    lineChart.setAnimated(false);
    lineChart.setTitle("Animated Line Chart");
    lineChart.setHorizontalGridLinesVisible(true);

    // Set Name for Series
    series1.setName("Series 1");
    series2.setName("Series 2");
    series3.setName("Series 3");

    // Add Chart Series
    lineChart.getData().addAll(series1, series2, series3);

    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(lineChart));
}


@Override
public void start(Stage stage) {
    stage.setTitle("Animated Line Chart Sample");
    init(stage);
    stage.show();


    executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool(new ThreadFactory() {
        @Override
        public Thread newThread(Runnable r) {
            Thread thread = new Thread(r);
            thread.setDaemon(true);
            return thread;
        }
    });

    AddToQueue addToQueue = new AddToQueue();
    executor.execute(addToQueue);
    //-- Prepare Timeline
    prepareTimeline();
}

private class AddToQueue implements Runnable {
    public void run() {
        try {
            // add a item of random data to queue
            dataQ1.add(Math.random());
            dataQ2.add(Math.random());
            dataQ3.add(Math.random());

            Thread.sleep(500);
            executor.execute(this);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

//-- Timeline gets called in the JavaFX Main thread
private void prepareTimeline() {
    // Every frame to take any data from queue and add to chart
    new AnimationTimer() {
        @Override
        public void handle(long now) {
            addDataToSeries();
        }
    }.start();
}

private void addDataToSeries() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) { //-- add 20 numbers to the plot+
        if (dataQ1.isEmpty()) break;
        series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>(xSeriesData++, dataQ1.remove()));
        series2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>(xSeriesData++, dataQ2.remove()));
        series3.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>(xSeriesData++, dataQ3.remove()));
    }
    // remove points to keep us at no more than MAX_DATA_POINTS
    if (series1.getData().size() > MAX_DATA_POINTS) {
        series1.getData().remove(0, series1.getData().size() - MAX_DATA_POINTS);
    }
    if (series2.getData().size() > MAX_DATA_POINTS) {
        series2.getData().remove(0, series2.getData().size() - MAX_DATA_POINTS);
    }
    if (series3.getData().size() > MAX_DATA_POINTS) {
        series3.getData().remove(0, series3.getData().size() - MAX_DATA_POINTS);
    }
    // update
    xAxis.setLowerBound(xSeriesData - MAX_DATA_POINTS);
    xAxis.setUpperBound(xSeriesData - 1);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
}
```

So I have this code which I have found it online.I am trying to read this code and understand what it does.I knew javaFX and understood this parts of it but I do not know other parts yet.But before I need to make sure that I can make this animation smoother.Then I can go into details..

I didn't manage to find out how to do it.What should I do for make it smoother?

Answer (score 1):

To get smooth animation out of your sample:

- Change `MAX_DATA_POINTS` from `50`, to `2_500`.
- Change `Thread.sleep(500)` to `Thread.sleep(10)`.

If you only update the chart twice a second (as in the example you posted), the animation will be jumpy.

If you update 30+ times per second, the animation will be smooth.  The human eye generally registers small frame to frame changes occurring at 30+ frames per second as smooth animation.  Refer to [wikipedia on "Frame rate and human vision"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frame_rate#Frame_rate_and_human_vision).

---

In general, I'd caution against using a code example like this that you found on the internet if you cannot get a good understanding of how it works and what it does by reviewing its code.  In particular, the sample code you provided executes on multiple threads.  If your requirements do not necessitate execution on multiple threads, then you probably should not use a solution such as this.